# Jquery not seeing a dynamically loaded class

Tags: php, jquery, dynamic

I've loaded some classes to a few html tags. They look ordinary in the console and my associated css is displaying correctly. I also have a little JQuery I want to apply that uses the same classes, but it doesn't seem to see just the classes that were loaded dynamically. I can get to the others just fine. It seems to be a timing issue. Obviously when the script runs, whatever it sees in the DOM doesn't include everything new I'm adding. I understand that JQuery used to have a .live which is now replaced .on and that in this situation it would require a handler, but I think I'm getting a little over my head. I'm still a little new to JQuery. How might I implement this here?

Here is the php that sets the variable...

```
$toggle = " visNone";
```

Here is the relevant html...

```
<div id="sampleOneReservation" class="Grid_12<?php echo $toggle; ?>">
```

And the relevant portion of the script...

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    if ($("#sampleOneReservation").hasClass("visNone")) {
        alert("This is not working!");
    }
});
```

Comment: try `class="Grid_12 <?php echo $toggle; ?>"` - also have a look at the generated html to see what values are there for the class

Comment: That looks like it should work fine. Since you're outputting the class with PHP, it should be available immediately to javascript. Are you sure the ready() method is firing (stick an alert at the top)? Have a sample page?

Comment: Check for browser console Javascript errors.

Comment: You may be using duplicate ID . Check it

Comment: Got the alert when moving the alert to top. No errors in the console.

Comment: duplicate ID's... Hadn't thought of that yet.

Comment: Moved ID to class and changed in JQuery. I thought that might be it, but no luck.

Comment: Correction. Duplicate ID's was the issue. I left an error in the code and didn't see it at first. Thanks to Miqdad Ali. Post the answer and I'll give credit where it's due.

Answer (score 1):

You have to load jquery file at the bottom of your html where you have set the class.

Answer (score 0):

try this, give space after "Grid_12"

```
class="Grid_12 <?php echo $toggle; ?>"
```

Comment: but there is a space in the variable `$toggle = " visNone";`

Comment: Yes, though I did run into that problem earlier, it now prints to the dev console with correct spaces and I can access the "Grid_12" class through JQuery without issue.